# How to create a file with invalid or special characters in its name?

Tags: windows-7, python, filenames

I'm trying to install some Python 2.7 module named `libwapiti` on Windows 7. While trying to install it, it asked me for several header (*.h) files which were not included in `MSVC2008ForPython27` and I'm trying to fix it.

Right know it asked for a file named: `sys/time.h` I copy-pasted the code inside a text file but when I try to rename it to what mentioned above, Windows says you can't create a filename with `/\?*<>|` and so on. What can I do?!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the system asks for a file named `time.h` in the folder named `sys`, isn't it?

You also may try to create a notepad++ file with your coding. This would be a proper place for the coding document, rather than a text file.

Microsoft support says

> To create, save, or rename a file, folder, or shortcut, use a valid
>   character that is not listed in the first error message listed in the
>   Symptoms section of this article.

Comment: No, the file exactly named `sys/time.h`. It exists. I saw some developers published its code for free use and I just copy-pasted one. That libwapiti module with all of its headers work normally on linux but here I need to get it running on Windows which does not let me to create it inside the proper directory due to its (silly!) name.

Comment: Really I don't think that Windows will let you to put such name.

Comment: The file cannot be exactly named `sys/time.h`. Neither Windows, Linux, Mac, or Python will allow you to use the character `/` in a file name.